# strangely "clipped" normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, censoring

I'm trying to model a behavior using a normal distribution. Now, when the range of the variable is bounded, instead of using a truncated normal distribution, values are "packed" at the extremities. Peak value is not affected.

In the figure hereunder, the orange curve is the normal distribution. The blue curve is the "clipped" or "packed" distribution when the variable is bounded in the [-500, 500] range.

[image]
What kind of law is that ? Do you know a distribution model for this kind of behavior?

Comment: How did you plot the density function: did you estimate it from observations (if so, how?), or did you calculate it (if so, you already know the formula for it).

Comment: The "theoretical" blue curve comes from Finite Elements Model. I try to approximate the distribution of stress in an analytical way. So, to summarize, the reference comes from calculations I use as if it has been observed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a Winsorized normal. This is similar to a trimmed or truncated normal, except rather than deleting the extreme cases, they are set equal to the largest (or smallest) remaining value.

E.g, in R

```
install.packages("DescTools")
library(DescTools)

set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(1000)
winx <- Winsorize(x)
plot(density(winx, minval = -3, maxval = 3))
```

yields a somewhat similar plot and a little fooling around with the limits could get it much closer. (Obviously, you'd start with a normal distribution that is similar to the one you plotted).

Comment: +1. Sometimes called a "[censored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censoring_(statistics)) normal distribution".

Comment: Winsorizing results in a 'spike' at the two bounds when you plot the density. In the plot given in the question points there are inflection points before the bounds are reached.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica That depends on the bounds.